# How do I see more than three notifications (in Big Sur)

Tags: notifications, big-sur

In Catalina the notification centre had a long list of notifications, most recent first. In Big Sur it only lists the top three. How can I configure it to show me more?

Yes, there is a button to show more, but I have to click this every time I open the notification centre, I want it to default to this view.